# CSS 3 Corner Ribbon rounded corner issue

Tags: css, rounded-corners

So, I'm trying to make a top right corner ribbon. I'm doing this successfuly but the issue that I have is that I cannot find a way to make the top right corner to have a slight border-radius of lets say 10px. I tried border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 10px (changing all the values) and as well as border-top-right-radius:10px and none of those worked. Any solution will be appreciated.

```css
.corner-ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid #ED5565;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}

.corner-ribbon .test-text {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 60px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="corner-ribbon">
  <span class="test-text">Some text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the given code, you can add a wrapper and make it the same size as your ribbon, then apply your border radius with overflow hidden. Since you are making the shape with borders so applying border radius on your existing elements would not work.

```css
.corner-ribbon {
  border-top: 100px solid #ED5565;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}

.corner-ribbon .test-text {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 60px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.wrapper {
  border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="corner-ribbon">
    <span class="test-text">Some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is it :))) thank you very much for your effort and time solving my problem.. highly appreciated..